# How to get current value of oracle sequence in ctl template

Tags: python, oracle, ctl, currval

I'm trying to ingest 3 csv into 3 three tables A,B,C respectively. Primary key of A is generated using SCHEMEA.SEQ_TAB_REC_ID.NEXTVAL  and B, C has foreign key column which is referring to A's primary key
I tried to put the direct sql query

```
select SEQ_TAB_REC_ID.CURRVAL FROM dual;
```

in the ctl. But it does not work Then I tried to put it like this

TAB_REC_ID  "TAB_STG.SEQ_TAB_REC_ID.CURRVAL",

It would be greatly appreciated if you could come up with a solution for getting the current value of sequence in the ctl either using the raw sql or by an expression inside the ctl template

Comment: If you are using Python (and not SQL\*Loader - please update your question tags) then you could look at using RETURNING INTO in the first INSERT statement, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#dml-returning-bind-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you can not. Sequence value should first be *fetched* (in this session) so that you could check its current value.

For example:

```
SQL> create sequence seq_tab_rec_id;

Sequence created.
```

If you try to find its current value:

```
SQL> select seq_tab_rec_id.currval from dual;
select seq_tab_rec_id.currval from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08002: sequence SEQ_TAB_REC_ID.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session
```

So: first fetch it ...

```
SQL> select seq_tab_rec_id.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
```

... and then you can check its current value:

```
SQL> select seq_tab_rec_id.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         1

SQL>
```

---

As of this:

> I'm trying to ingest a csv into a table using the **oracle ctl template**

If I understood it correctly, you're talking about CTL file which is the Oracle SQL*Loader's **control file**. Is it? Syntax you tried (the 2nd one) looks like that. If that's so, then it *should* work - it does for me. Here's an example (I'll reuse sequence I already created):

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
id "seq_tab_rec_id.nextval",
name
)

begindata
1,Little
2,Foot
```

ID values will be *discarded* and replaced by sequence's values.

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test46.ctl log=test46.log

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sri Stu 2 07:15:16 2022
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test46.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Little
         3 Foot

SQL>
```

So ... it works.

---

Finally:

> column is referring to another table as foreign key

I don't think that SQL*Loader is capable of doing that (looking up into another table's column to find the parent key value). Perhaps you should switch to something else, something which is more *flexible* in terms of programming. That would be an **external table**.

Basically, your CSV file would act as if it were an ordinary Oracle table. You'd then be able to write SQL (or PL/SQL, i.e. procedures, not only queries) against it. Doing so, I guess that you'd accomplish your task much easier. Certainly, YMMV (as @JL Peyret commented).